# Java JDBC batchExecute insert

Tags: java, jdbc

I am using JDBC addBatch and batchExecute for insert statements. 
I have autocommit mode to on. My problem is, when I have for example 20 inserts, and insert number 10 raises an exception (for example null values not allowed), no data is inserted. Shouldn't be the first 10 ok statements be inserted?.

My code:

```
        try {
            int[] results =  stmt.executeBatch();                
            return results;
        } catch (BatchUpdateException e) {
            int[] tmpres = e.getUpdateCounts();                
            for (i = 0; i < tmpres.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(tmpres[i]);
            }
        }
```

I see on the output that the update count of the first 10 statements is 1. So why no data is inserted?

Best regards,
Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers to this question are somewhat misleading, at least with regard to the general case.

In most cases, when using `executeBatch()` with `setAutoCommit(true)`:

- the statements in the batch are *not* wrapped in an implicit transaction, and
- the statements processed prior to the BatchUpdateException *will* be committed.

This is definitely true for MySQL Connector/J (with `rewriteBatchedStatements=false`, which is the default), the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver, Derby, and HSQLDB. (I just ran actual Java code to confirm.)

As with many other aspects of JDBC, the actual behaviour *in your particular case* depends on the specific implementation of the JDBC driver you are using.

Comment: To complete the picture: Oracle and DB2 behave as you describe. Postgres treats the batch as a single transaction.

Comment: Firebird behaves the same as Postgres (the batch is considered a single transcation)

Comment: You're right, my answer sounded like "this is always given" which is not true.

Comment: Oh, that is a problem for my application. Can I somehow check on runtime if the driver handles the execute batch as one transaction?

Comment: @Peter - *"Can I somehow check on runtime ..."* - Two approaches come to mind: (1) You could use `.getMetaData().getDriverName()` on the Connection and compare the driver name with a list of known names that do (or don't) handle a batch as an implicit transaction. (2) On startup you could create a tiny test batch (containing one success followed by one failure) and then see how it behaves.

Comment: @Peter ... however, it might be better if your code used `setAutoCommit(false)` and *explicitly* handled the transaction behaviour, rather than relying on the (possibly inconsistent) behaviour of different JDBC drivers with `setAutoCommit(true)`.

Comment: @GordThompson Thanks, I used the approach to set Auto Commit false for the batches.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like in your configuration, all the statements inside one batch are in fact executed in **one transaction**. So if any of the inserts fail, the whole transaction (that's the whole batch) will be rolled back. Even with autocommit on.

Answer (score 0):

In this case **all the statements are involved in the same transaction** so any statement that will cause an error will rollback the whole transaction.